# Unspecified behaviour about "object having more than one object representation"

Tags: c, c99, unspecified-behavior, bit-representation

Still struggling with C (C99) undefined and unspecified behaviours.

This time it is the following Unspecified Behaviour (Annex J.1):

> The representation used when storing a value in an object that has
> more than one object representation for that value (6.2.6.1).

The corresponding section 6.2.6.1 states:

> Where an operator is applied to a value that has more than one object
> representation, which object representation is used shall not affect
> the value of the result<sup>43)</sup>. Where a value is stored in an object using
> a type that has more than one object representation for that value, it
> is unspecified which representation is used, but a trap representation
> shall not be generated.

with the following note 43:

> It is possible for objects `x` and `y` with the same effective type `T` to
> have the same value when they are accessed as objects of type `T`, but
> to have different values in other contexts. In particular, if `==` is
> defined for type `T`, then `x == y` does not imply that `memcmp(&x, &y, sizeof(T)) == 0`. Furthermore, `x == y` does not necessarily imply that `x`
> and `y` have the same value; other operations on values of type `T` may
> distinguish between them.

I don't even understand what would be *a value that has more than one object representation*. Is it related for example to a floating point representation of 0 (negative and positive zero) ?

Comment: Think about 0 in ones complement.

Comment: As for other operations may distinguish between them, consider bitwise operations on the two representations of 0 in ones complement (the two representations of 0 being "all bits zero" and "all bits one").

Comment: Objects can have bits that don't correspond to the value , e.g. `long double` commonly uses 128 bits of storage but only 80 bits of value and the rest are random or disregarded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of this language is the C standard going *well* out of its way to allow for continued use on Burroughs B-series mainframes (AFAICT the *only* surviving ones-complement architecture).  Unless you have to work with those, or certain uncommon microcontrollers, or you're seriously into retrocomputing, you can safely assume that the integer types have only one object representation per value, and that they have no padding bits.  You can also safely assume that all integer types have no trap representations, *except* that you must take this line of J.2

> [the behavior is undefined if ...] the value of an object <s>with automatic storage duration</s> is used while it is indeterminate

as if it were normative and as if the crossed-out words were not present.  (This rule is not supported by a close reading of the actual normative text, but it is nonetheless the rule adopted by all of the current generation of optimizing compilers.)

Concrete examples of types that *can* have more than one object representation for a value on a modern, non-exotic implementation include:

- `_Bool`: the effect of overwriting a `_Bool` object with the representation of an integer value other than an appropriately sized 0 or 1 is unspecified.
- pointer types: some architectures *ignore* the low bits of a pointer to a type whose minimum alignment is greater than 1 (e.g. `(int*)0x8000_0000` and `(int*)0x8000_0001` might be treated as referring to the same `int` object; this is an intentional hardware feature, facilitating the use of tagged pointers)
- floating point types: IEC 60559 allows all of the many representations of NaN to be treated identically (and possibly squashed together) by the hardware.  (Note: +0 and −0 are distinct values in IEEE floating point, not different representations of the same value.)

These are also the scalar types that can have trap representations in modern implementations.  In particular, Annex F specifically declares the behavior of signaling NaN to be undefined, even though it's well-defined in an abstract implementation of IEC 60559.

Comment: Floating-point formats may also have multiple representations of numbers, not just NaNs, such as 91•10^2 and 9.1•10^3.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I'd consider a floating point format where normal numbers have more than one representation to be "exotic" nowadays.  The only one that comes to mind is IBM long double (a 128-bit format composed of two 64-bit doubles, to be interpreted as their sum).

Comment: They are part of the IEEE 754-2008 standard, for decimal formats, and I think IBM and others have been using them actively.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't even understand what would be a value that has more than one object representation. Is it related for example to a floating point representation of 0 (negative and positive zero) ?

No, negative and positive zero are different values.

In practice, you probably don't need to worry about values with different object representations, but one possible example would involve integer types that include padding bits.  For example, suppose your implementation provided a 15-(value-)bit unsigned integer type, whose storage size was 16 bits.  Suppose also that the padding bit in the representation of that type were completely ignored for the purpose of evaluating objects (that is, that the type afforded no trap representations).  Then each value representable by that type would have two distinct object representations, differing in the value of the padding bit.

The standard says that in such a case, you cannot rely on a particular choice between those value representations to be made under any given circumstances, but also that it doesn't matter when such objects are operands of any C operator.  Note 43 clarifies that the difference may nevertheless be felt in other ways.

Answer (score -1):

As you suspected, `-0.0` is a good candidate but only for the last phrase:

> Furthermore, `x == y` does not necessarily imply that `x` and `y` have the same value; other operations on values of type `T` may distinguish between them.

```
double x = 0.0;
double y = -0.0;
if (x == y) {
    printf("x and y have the same value\n");
}
if (memcmp(&x, &y, sizeof(double)) {
    printf("x and y have a different representation\n");
}
if (1 / x != 1 / y) {
    printf("1/x and 1/y have a different value\n");
}
```

Another example of a value with more than one possible representation is NaN. `0.0 / 0.0` evaluates to a NaN value, which may have a different representation from the one produced by the macro `NAN` or another operation producing NaN or even the same expression `0.0 / 0.0` evaluated again. `memcmp()` may show that the representations differ. This example however does not really illustrate the purpose of the Standard's quote in the question as these values do not match per the `==` operator.

The text you quoted from the Annex J seems to specifically address some rare architectures (nowadays) that have padding bits and/or representations of negative numbers with 2 different representations for `0`. All modern systems use [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) to represent negative numbers, where all bit patterns represent different values, but 4 decades ago you some fairly common mainframes used [ones' complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement) or [sign and magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Sign-and-magnitude_method) where 2 different bit patterns could represent the value `0`.

Comment: Negative and positive zero are _not_ the same value in an implementation conforming to Annex F.

Comment: @zwol: C implementations do not have to conform to Annex F. Further, even though IEEE-754 distinguishes −0 and +0, they are an example for the quoted text “Furthermore, `x == y` does not necessarily imply that `x` and `y` have the same value; other operations on values of type `T` may distinguish between them.”

Comment: @zwol: You are correct, `0.0` and `-0.0` are different values, I amended the answer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: correct, I amended the answer along your suggestion.

Comment: `1/x` causes undefined behaviour (C11 6.5.5/5 division by zero,  does not have any conformance exceptions)